# How to color/identify plot points by date

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a `geom_line` plot in `ggplot2` to show some call center data over time.  I have my graph built as I want it, but I would like to identify specific dates (Monday's to be specific.. IE, 1/7, 1/14, 1/21, 1/28, 2/4, etc) with something like a special marker/color.. currently the dates are character format (how they were given to me), but with `lubridate` I believe they could be converted with little/no issue if needed.  Is this possible?

I am super novice at plotting with R, I have gotten to this point from other SO posts and a few 'cheat sheets'.

The only 'relevant' post I could find that directly mentions using any kind of function with ggplot is here: http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/#use-a-function-to-alter-labels.  This doesn't exactly fit what I am looking for either.

Here is my code as it sits:

```
a <-  ggplot(cleantargetcounts)+
   geom_line(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION, group = DISPOSITION), size = 1.2)+
   scale_color_manual(values = c(Approval = "dark green",Denial = "red",Skip = "orange"))+
   geom_point(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION),size = 3.2)+
   geom_text_repel(aes(label=cleantargetcounts$TOTAL, x=DTE,y=TOTAL))+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))+
   labs( x = "Date", y = "Disposition Count", title ="Disposition Count by Date")
```

Here is what my graph looks like currently: 
[image: no markings]

and here is a basic idea of what I am looking for:
[image: Mondays identified]

It would not matter to me HOW Monday's are identified.. whether it is a date colored, the plotted points are different.. just as long as they are easy to point out.

**Here's my data:**

```
    DTE        DISPOSITION TOTAL  
   <chr>      <chr>       <int>  
 1 2019-01-08 Approval      454 
 2 2019-01-08 Denial        120   
 3 2019-01-08 Skip          135
 4 2019-01-09 Approval      425 
 5 2019-01-09 Denial        141
 6 2019-01-09 Skip          203 
 7 2019-01-10 Approval      448 
 8 2019-01-10 Denial        112
 9 2019-01-10 Skip          169 
10 2019-01-11 Approval      666
```

**Attempted codes provided by Heck1**

```
cleantargetcounts$weekday <- wday(ymd(cleantargetcounts$DTE), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)

a <-  ggplot(cleantargetcounts)+
  geom_line(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION, group = DISPOSITION), size = 1.2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Approval = "dark green",Denial = "red",Skip = "orange"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION),size = 3.2)+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=cleantargetcounts$TOTAL, x=DTE,y=TOTAL))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1, color = ifelse(cleantargetcounts$weekday == "Monday", "red", "black")))+
  labs( x = "Date", y = "Disposition Count", title ="Disposition Count by Date")
```

which provides the following plot
[image: Heck1 Example]

Which is a bit odd as it correctly identified the days of the week in my data frame.

```
 DTE        DISPOSITION TOTAL weekday
  <chr>      <chr>       <int> <ord>  
1 2019-01-07 Approval      455 Monday 
2 2019-01-07 Denial         95 Monday 
3 2019-01-07 Skip          154 Monday 
4 2019-01-08 Approval      454 Tuesday
5 2019-01-08 Denial        120 Tuesday
6 2019-01-08 Skip          135 Tuesday
```

**Attempting Jason's answer**
I get an error that I am not familiar with

```
 df_tidy <- cleantargetcounts %>% 
gather(DISPOSITION, TOTAL, -DTE) %>% 
mutate(dow = wday(ymd(cleantargetcounts$DTE, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE)))


Error: Column `dow` must be length 306 (the number of rows) or one, not 155
In addition: Warning message:
 2 failed to parse.
```

**correction to Jason's answer**
I had to modify part of Jason's answer to get it working correctly for me as follows:

```
df_tidy <- cleantargetcounts2 %>% mutate(dow = wday(DTE, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE))
df_regions <- df_tidy %>% filter(dow == "Mon") %>% mutate(min = DTE - 0.5,
                                                          max = min + 1,
                                                          ymin = -Inf,
                                                          ymax = +Inf)

a <-  ggplot(df_tidy)+
  geom_line(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION, group = DISPOSITION), size = 1.2)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Approval = "dark green",Denial = "red",Skip = "orange"))+
  geom_point(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION),size = 3.2)+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=df_tidy$TOTAL, x=DTE,y=TOTAL))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))+
  labs( x = "Date", y = "Disposition Count", title ="Disposition Count by Date")+
  geom_rect(data = df_regions,aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2, color = NA)
```

Which produced the most accurate end result I was looking for like this:

[image: Working Example via Jason]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and make a reproducible example, however, based on your pictures, the following should get you what you want. In short, just pass "filtered" data into a `geom` call:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(101)

df <- tibble(
  date = seq(ymd("2019-01-07"), ymd("2019-03-18"), by = "day"),
  approval = runif(n = 71, 225, 800),
  denial = runif(n = 71, 85, 120),
  skip = runif(n = 71, 120, 300)
)

df %>%
  gather(metric, value, -date) %>%
  mutate(
    dow = wday(date, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = metric)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(dow == "Mon"), color = "deeppink", size = 3)
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could create a `highlights` `data.frame` like this and pass this to `geom_rect`:

```r
df_tidy <-
  df %>%
  gather(metric, value, -date) %>%
  mutate(
    dow = wday(date, abbr = TRUE, label = TRUE)
  )

df_regions <- 
  df_tidy %>%
  filter(dow == "Mon") %>%
  mutate(
    min = date - 0.5, # we want the highlighted region 'around' the point, not on the point.
    max = min + 1,
    ymin = -Inf,
    ymax = +Inf
  )

df_tidy %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, color = metric)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_rect(
    data = df_regions, 
    aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), 
    fill = "orange", alpha = 0.2, color = NA
  )
```

[image: Highlighted with Rects]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I REALLY like the idea of the vertical bars highlighting the dates.. When I try to adapt your code I get a "failed to parse" error that I do not quite understand.  I will add the code I tried and the error to my OP.

Comment: @Checht - you need to make sure your `dates` field is actually a date, and not a character vector. Something like `cleantargetcounts %>% mutate(dates = mdy(dates))` is probably what you need towards the front of your code. Try working with that and if you get stuck, you may want to open a new question.

Comment: This works beautifully when I corrected the dates from CHARACTER to date.  The only other 'gripe' I have is this removed my dates under each data point and replaced it with a more general date with what appears to be 1 to 2 week breaks.. Is it possible to leave the dates under each data point?

Comment: @Checht yes, just add `scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day")` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your data, a solution with `lubridate` would look like this:

```
 library(lubridate)
 cleantargetcounts$weekday <- wday(ymd(cleantargetcounts$DTE), label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```

Output of `cleantargetcounts$weekday` should be a vector with `"Monday" "Tuesday"` and so on. Then to mark mondays on your plot you could use:

```
a <-  ggplot(cleantargetcounts)+
   geom_line(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION, group = DISPOSITION), size = 1.2)+
   scale_color_manual(values = c(Approval = "dark green",Denial = "red",Skip = "orange"))+
   geom_point(aes(x=DTE, y=TOTAL, color = DISPOSITION),size = 3.2)+
   geom_text_repel(aes(label=cleantargetcounts$TOTAL, x=DTE,y=TOTAL))+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1,
colour = ifelse(cleantargetcounts$weekday == "Monday",
                                         "red","black)
    ))+
   labs( x = "Date", y = "Disposition Count", title ="Disposition Count by Date")
```

Comment: I will definitely be messing with this option.. though 'right out of the box' it isn't working quite 100%.  The added column is spot on (Mondays are tied to the correct dates) but the plot is also coloring the following Tuesday and wednesday as RED as well.  I will let you know if I can get this working.